# got error 404 while installing shibboleth, unable to get idp/status

Tags: shibboleth

I am new to this shibboleth Identity Provider and evaluating shibboleth want to use for Identity provider for our application, tried to install shibboleth
2.4.0, after following detailed steps form documentation.

https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/IdPInstall

when try to Download it give version 3.0.0, which is alpha version , which is not recommended to use in production env, so I started using version 2.4.0,
after running ./install.sh and deploy idp.war in tomcat

```
   get 404 error  https://localhost:8443/idp/status
```

Am I using stable version, which version should I use I can see there are many versions available after 2.4.0, followed this below link I had download shibboleth zip

```
 http://shibboleth.net/downloads/identity-provider/
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got resolve ,by using shibboleth2.4.4 , able to get status
also able to https://localhost:8443/idp/profile/Status,